# How do you add flag in $() in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have the following bash script and seems the -n flag is always interpreted as string in echo

```
echo Hello, who am I talking to?
read login_name
login_name=$(echo -n $login_name | base64)
echo $login_name | base64 --decode
```

How do i correct that, or is there any other better syntax for my script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better use more portable `printf` instead of `echo -n` and use `read -p` with correct quoting;

```
read -p 'Hello, who am I talking to? ' login_name
login_name=$(printf '%s' "$login_name" | base64)
printf '%s' "$login_name" | base64 --decode
echo
```

PS: Just to clarify that there is nothing special about using any flag inside `$(...)` so one can use it like this:

```
dt=$(date -u '+%Y/%m/%d')
echo "$dt"
```

Comment: I need to encode without the line return from echo that’s why I added the -n, does ur code remove line break

Comment: Yes of course, `printf '%s'` doesn't print any newline

Comment: But in general how do u execute with flags in $()

Comment: There is nothing special about `$(...)` here. One can use: `dt=$(date -u '+%Y/%m/%d')`

Comment: just need to single quote the variable ?

Comment: For variables to expand we need to use double quotes otherwise single quote works better in other cases

Comment: if you could add an answer to demonstrate how to add flag in $(), i'll mark +1

Comment: @FanCheung It has nothing to do with `$( )`, and everything to do with `echo`. Some versions of `echo`, if their first argument starts with "-", interpret it as flags. Some don't. Basically, it's not safe to either try to pass flag options to `echo`, or to use it with a string that starts with "-". `printf` is more complicated to use, but much more predictable and controllable.

Comment: thanks @GordonDavisson that really helps clearing the idea up